# HC_06 не работает корректно с arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

я загрузил в arduino uno этот код:

```
int val;
int LED = 13;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    val = Serial.read();
    // При символе "1" включаем светодиод
    if (val == '1')
    {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    }
    // При символе "0" выключаем светодиод
    if ( val == '0')
    {
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

подключился к HC-06 с android с помощью bluetooth terminal. Ввел 0 ничего не произошло, ввел 1 тоже ничего не произошло. Пробовал подавать питание отдельно с блока питание, тоже не помогло. Решил перепрошить модуль. Подключал и через делитель напряжения и напрямую, ничего не работает. Пытался через COM порт из IDE тоже не работает, пытался через termite с пк тоже не работает. На AT команды модуль не отвечает. Но у меня новый модуль HC-06, сзади у него снизу написано zs-040.

Comment: Попробуйте char val.